# Create a new columns based on keywords in YAKE

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyword

I'm trying to use YAKE to extract the keywords from a list of books' summaries.

```
df = {'Book': [1, 2], 'Summary': ['text definition includes the original words of something written, printed, or spoken', 'example of the Lorem ipsum placeholder text on a green and white webpage']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
```

Then I tried to use a loop and extract 1 keyword from each summary:

```
for i in df['Summary']:
  language = "en"
  max_ngram_size = 1
  deduplication_threshold = 0.9
  numOfKeywords = 2
  custom_kw_extractor = yake.KeywordExtractor(lan=language, n=max_ngram_size, dedupLim=deduplication_threshold, top=numOfKeywords, features=None)
  keywords = custom_kw_extractor.extract_keywords(i)
  for kw, w in keywords:
    print(kw)
```

Th output is:

```
printed
Lorem
```

However, I'd like to add them as a new column in the same dataframe. The final output should be:

| Book | Summary | Keywods |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text definition includes the original words of something written, printed, or spoken | printed |
| 2 | example of the Lorem ipsum placeholder text on a green and white webpage | Lorem |

I tried to make a new list

```
df['keywords'] = kw
```

but it didn't work! It's been a while since I used Python and pandas and I don't seem to remember to do that!

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**

> 1 keyword was for simplicity but I'd love it if I can generalise it to multiple keywords

For multiple keywords, change `numOfKeywords` and `lambda` function:

```
language = 'en'
max_ngram_size = 1
deduplication_threshold = 0.9
numOfKeywords = 3  # <- Multiple keywords
custom_kw_extractor = yake.KeywordExtractor(lan=language, n=max_ngram_size,
                                            dedupLim=deduplication_threshold,
                                            top=numOfKeywords, features=None)

extract_keywords = lambda x: [k[0] for k in custom_kw_extractor.extract_keywords(x)]
df['TopKeyword'] = df['Summary'].apply(extract_keywords)
```

Output:

| Book | Summary | TopKeyword |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text definition includes the original words of something written, printed, or spoken | ['printed', 'text', 'written'] |
| 2 | example of the Lorem ipsum placeholder text on a green and white webpage | ['Lorem', 'webpage', 'ipsum'] |

To get a string instead of a list, update `lambda function`:

```
extract_keywords = lambda x: ','.join(k[0] for k in custom_kw_extractor.extract_keywords(x))
```

Output:

| Book | Summary | TopKeyword |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text definition includes the original words of something written, printed, or spoken | printed,text,written |
| 2 | example of the Lorem ipsum placeholder text on a green and white webpage | Lorem,webpage,ipsum |

---

**Old answer**

```
extract_keywords = lambda x: ','.join(k[0] for k in custom_kw_extractor.extract_keywords(x))
df['Keywords'] = df['Summary'].apply(extract_keywords)
```

You don't need a loop here, `apply` can do it for you.

```
language = 'en'
max_ngram_size = 1
deduplication_threshold = 0.9
numOfKeywords = 1
custom_kw_extractor = yake.KeywordExtractor(lan=language, n=max_ngram_size,
                                            dedupLim=deduplication_threshold,
                                            top=numOfKeywords, features=None)

extract_keyword = lambda x: custom_kw_extractor.extract_keywords(x)[0][0]
df['TopKeyword'] = df['Summary'].apply(extract_keyword)
```

Output:

| Book | Summary | TopKeyword |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text definition includes the original words of something written, printed, or spoken | printed |
| 2 | example of the Lorem ipsum placeholder text on a green and white webpage | Lorem |

Comment: One minute too late? ;)

Comment: OP asked for 1 keyword if I understood it correctly..

Comment: Yeah all good.. 1+.

Comment: Thank you, 1 keyword was for simplicity but I'd love it if I can generalise it to multiple keywords.

Comment: Do you want a list of keywords `[kw1, kw2, kw3]` or a string `'kw1, kw2, kw3'`?

Comment: @Sam. I updated my answer. Can you check it please?

Comment: It works beautifully - I will use the list, thank YOU!!

Answer (score 4):

Try `df.Summary.apply`:

```
import pandas as pd
import yake

language = "en"
max_ngram_size = 1
deduplication_threshold = 0.9
numOfKeywords = 1
custom_kw_extractor = yake.KeywordExtractor(lan=language, n=max_ngram_size, dedupLim=deduplication_threshold, top=numOfKeywords, features=None)

df = {'Book': [1, 2], 'Summary': ['text definition includes the original words of something written, printed, or spoken', 'example of the Lorem ipsum placeholder text on a green and white webpage']}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

df['Keywords'] = df.Summary.apply(lambda x : custom_kw_extractor.extract_keywords(x)[0][0])
```

```
|    |   Book | Summary                                                                              | Keywords   |
|---:|-------:|:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|:-----------|
|  0 |      1 | text definition includes the original words of something written, printed, or spoken | printed    |
|  1 |      2 | example of the Lorem ipsum placeholder text on a green and white webpage             | Lorem      |
```

Or with `to_numpy()`:

```
df['keywords'] = [custom_kw_extractor.extract_keywords(d)[0][0] for d in df.Summary.to_numpy()]
```

Key words as lists using `to_numpy()`, since it is usually faster than `df.apply`:

```
df['Keywords']  = [[s[0] for s in custom_kw_extractor.extract_keywords(d)] for d in df.Summary.to_numpy()]
```

```
|    |   Book | Summary                                                                              | Keywords                                               |
|---:|-------:|:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|:-------------------------------------------------------|
|  0 |      1 | text definition includes the original words of something written, printed, or spoken | ['printed', 'text', 'written', 'spoken', 'definition'] |
|  1 |      2 | example of the Lorem ipsum placeholder text on a green and white webpage             | ['Lorem', 'webpage', 'ipsum', 'placeholder', 'text']
```

Or if you want comma separated strings:

```
df['Keywords']  = [','.join([s[0] for s in custom_kw_extractor.extract_keywords(d)]) for d in df.Summary.to_numpy()]
```

```
|    |   Book | Summary                                                                              | Keywords                               |
|---:|-------:|:-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|:---------------------------------------|
|  0 |      1 | text definition includes the original words of something written, printed, or spoken | printed,text,written,spoken,definition |
|  1 |      2 | example of the Lorem ipsum placeholder text on a green and white webpage             | Lorem,webpage,ipsum,placeholder,text   |
```

Comment: Thank you for your help - now I remember using both `.apply` and `to_numpy()` is very useful! This example includes one keyword for simplicity - what if we have multiple keywords - am not sure how to index them. I can't use `extract_keyword = lambda x: custom_kw_extractor.extract_keywords(x)[:][0]` assuming that we have `numOfKeywords = 6` - can we use your answer if we have multiple keywords?

Comment: Yeah sure, one moment.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer, this is VERY helpful- I learned from both approaches (you and Corralien) - I really appreciate that!

Comment: Also, check the performance details on `to_numpy()` vs. `df.apply`